# Resizing gif image causes loss of quality

Tags: asp.net, graphics, gdi+, image-resizing

I'm using `Graphics.DrawImage()` to resize images in my ASP.NET application.

This is working fine with all image formats, except gif.

Here is my original image:

[image]

When I resize to `300px` it returns:

[image]

The code I'm using is:

```
 Dim postedFile as new Bitmap("flower.gif")
 Dim bmpOut As System.Drawing.Bitmap
 Dim Format As ImageFormat = postedFile.RawFormat
 bmpOut = New Bitmap(width, height)
 Dim g As Graphics = Graphics.FromImage(bmpOut)
 g.InterpolationMode = InterpolationMode.High
 g.DrawImage(postedFile, 0, 0, width, height)
 postedFile.Dispose()
 Return bmpOut
 bmpOut.Dispose()
```

I've also tried using all of the `InterpolationMode`'s available, including `InterpolationMode.HighQualityBicubic`, but the image quality is still just as poor.

Why is this happening, and how can I prevent the image quality loss?

Comment: What if try InterpolationMode.HighQualityBicubic?

Comment: @x2. The image quality is just as poor with `InterpolationMode.HighQualityBicubic`

Comment: What other interpolation options have you tried?

Comment: @ChrisF - All of the available options

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The problem is not in the resizing code you posted. I ran using the large image you posted and the result looks great. Your problem arises when you save your newly created 24 bits-per-pixel image to a new gif - with is 8bpp. You have basically two options:

1. Implement code to produce an optimized color palette for the new gif
   (or maybe just use the palette from the original image)
2. Save to .png instead - which is a completely superior format

Comment: So it's taking the gif image, converting it to a more high-res bitmap image, then reducing quality to save it back to a gif. I think its within the specs for me to save it as png. I'll test doing this to see if it fixes the issue, cheers @danbystrom

Comment: Cheers thats sorted my issue!

Answer (score 0):

If you are saving the resized picture as .gif, I see no reason why this can't happen in the saved .gif. .gif's are limited to 256 colors (unless some hacks are done) and your resized imaged after all the manipulations may have well more than 256. Also, I wouldn't be surprised to find out that whatever routine you're using to convert images to .gif's isn't very concerned about quality.

Comment: `Also, I wouldn't be surprised to find out that whatever routine you're using to convert images to .gif's isn't very concerned about quality.`. What reason do you have for presuming this? You can see the function I'm using to resize the code. I don't think there is anything to "find out".

Comment: @Curt: Or you may not be using the conversion/saving function properly even if it has quality-related options. I get similar bad results as yours when saving resized gif in XnView using Bayer with 256 colors or Floyd-Steinberg with 16 colors. Floyd-Steinberg with 128 or more colors produces a much much better image. Still, I don't know something. Did the resized image look that bad on the screen even before being saved as .gif or did the distortion happen during saving? If it's the latter, where's the code for saving?

Answer (score 0):

This is not about interpolation, it is because ColorPalette is not set for target image. You have to quantize. See example at http://glennjones.net/2005/10/high-quality-dynamically-resized-images-with-dot-net/